# How should a military society function

Tags: culture, politics, alternate-history, government, military

I am developing a made up nation known as the Imperial Republic of Vitami. This nation is ultimately based around knowing and being masters of warfare.

Real world basic training is early childhood education for them, anyone that doesn't serve the military is shunned and at least restricted to some rights and privileges the rest of society have and the nation's constitution is also the code of honor that all people of the nation abide by.

I am trying to figure out the history on how would such a nation would be born out of existence any ideas of what I should write an add to it?

Comment: The classic examples are Sparta (vide L.Dutch's answer) and the Zulu nation. Warrior societies usually don't end well. The Zulus, in particular, depended on a continual program of conquest to gain the resources they needed but didn't & couldn't produce themselves because the male population were mostly warriors.

Comment: Do you really mean ANYONE who doesn't serve the military is shunned? Farmers? Doctors? Teachers? Stay at home parents? Or do you mean everyone has to serve a term of military service before becoming a farmer, doctor, parent, etc? Military service in wartime results in a lot of disabled veterans (especially in historical periods with low tech medicine). Are these men and women shunned once they are no longer combat-ready? Saying what technology level and time period you are thinking of would help people to answer.

Comment: I am going by modern and the shunning are on those that never served what's so ever and really only happens with foreigners as they are given some leg room to not serve in the armed forces should they migrate to vitami

Comment: You can look at Prussia. I'm not sure how much they were actually militarized, but maybe it'll give you some ideas. After all, there's quote about them: "Prussia was not a country with an army, but an army with a country"

Answer (score 3):

Your Vitami sound pretty much like [Sparta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoge).

> The agōgē (Greek: ἀγωγή in Attic Greek, or ἀγωγά, agōgá in Doric Greek) was the rigorous education and training program mandated for all male Spartan citizens, except for the firstborn son in the ruling houses, Eurypontid and Agiad. The training involved learning stealth, cultivating loyalty to the Spartan group, military training (e.g., pain tolerance), hunting, dancing, singing, and social (communicating) preparation.
>
> According to folklore, agoge was introduced by the semi-mythical Spartan law-giver Lycurgus but its origins are thought to be between the 7th and 6th centuries BC when the state trained male citizens from the ages of seven to twenty-one.
>
> The aim of the system was to produce strong and capable warriors to serve in the Spartan army. It encouraged conformity and the importance of the Spartan state over one's personal interest and generated the future elites of Sparta. The men would become the "walls of Sparta" because Sparta was the only Greek city with no defensive walls after they had been demolished at the order of Lycurgus. Discipline was strict and the males were encouraged to fight amongst themselves to determine the strongest member of the group.

If you get inspiration from the history of classical Sparta you have a pretty good starting point. Hint: the system [doesn't scale up really much](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/67257/30492)

Comment: I know of it, but what i mean is why would they do it even sparta had a reason for becoming a warrior society

Comment: @ConnorLonergan, offering flowers to your enemy doesn't protect your city.

Comment: true but one would need an enemy and it would have to be a serious one that a whole civilization would be military

Comment: I disagree with that. Sparta was Sparta way before the Persians attacked Greece. Licurgus is said to have demolished the city wall in order to force the Spartans to be the city walls.

Comment: With the reason being that it would make sparta famous, which the oracle was right about

Comment: The basic reason why Sparta was a grim militaristic society was that they ruled over a large population of serfs ("[helots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helots)"); Sparta was the only Greek city-state with a sizeable territory. The Spartiates *had to* be fearsome warriors in order to keep the subjugated populations under control. The flip side is that although Sparta was powerful, it was also barren of art, science, culture and so on; of how many Spartan sculptors, playwrights, philosophers or writers have you heard?

Answer (score 0):

Adding another element to this, look at plains Indian's warrior societies.

http://historum.com/american-history/24966-lakota-warrior-societies.html

These were subsets of the tribe.  Some tribes had multiple societies.  You might be able to draw parallels with the Phratries in greek society.

Answer (score 0):

Well the question you have to ask is, why is the society so militaristically inclined? Is is because of survival, is there an ever looming threat real or imagined? Is this how the government keeps a tight hold over its populace? Was there a global war or crisis, and so the military step in but there wasn't really a reason for them to back down? Is there perhaps a cultural or religious motive behind the militarisation of thr nation?

There are of course multiple real workd examples of societies with a strong military presence/martial culture, there's quite a few fictional examples you can look at two. Take a gander at a few cultures, they'll do you good.